# Specify Column Range Except Second-to-last Row

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently using `SUM` on an entire column with the following formula:

```
=SUM(A2:A)
```

Unfortunately this total is displayed on the last row of this column, so it creates a circular reference, `#REF`, there that I need to get rid of. How can I make it so that it selects the column starting from the second row until the **second-to-last**?

I could change the formula manually every time I enter a new row, but that's not ideal at all.

**Pseudocode**

```
=SUM(A2:A[last row - 1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
=sum(indirect("A2:A"&row()-1))
```